# How to tell 'find' command to jump to a position and search?

Tags: find, directory, man, cd-command, header-file

I'm preparing headers for a C++ project and I decided to use `find` to get include option to other header files. To list the right path, I need to use `cd` with it, like:

```
cd 'PATH/TO/HEADER/FILE'
find ../../../
```

And only this way I can get the list of header directory to copy-paste to the header file. After that, I had to:

```
cd 'PATH/TO/MY/PROJECT'
```

To switch back to project path.

It's inconvenient to use `cd` often, so, can I tell `find` command to automatically 'jump' to the directory and search? I read through the man page and can't figure it out.

`find PATH/TO/HEADER/FILE` is not a solution because I deliberately want pathnames to start with `../../../`.

Comment: Why not just use `find PATH/TO/HEADER/FILE`? There's no reason to `cd` to the directory where the file might be located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the `cd` and `find` in a subshell:

```
(cd 'PATH/TO/HEADER/FILE' && find ../../..)
```

That way, only the current working directory of the subshell is affected.

You could make it a function or script, here using GNU `realpath`:

```
findfrom() (
  dir=${1?}; shift
  reldir=$(realpath --relative-to="$dir" .) || exit
  cd -- "$dir" && find "$reldir" "$@"
)
```

Recent versions of GNU `env` also have a `-C`/`--chdir` option to change the working directory before executing the command:

```
env -C PATH/TO/HEADER/FILE find ../../..
```

Also note that you can always do `cd -` to get back to the directory you were in before the last successful `cd`.

csh-like and Korn-like shells also support a working directory stack which you manipulate with `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd`. In `zsh`, you can tell `cd` to automatically use that stack with the `autopushd` option, and navigate that stack with `cd +2`, `cd -2`... or access it with the `$dirstack` array or the `~2`, `~+2`, `~-2` tilde expansions.